# Spark: Loading CSV with different no of columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm loading a CSV file using Spark's csv loader and transforming it into a specific `Dataset` by providing a `case class` schema and by using `.as[T]`.

```
spark.read
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
  .schema(schemaOf[T])
  .csv(filePath)
  .as[T]
```

My question here is, I have more than one system sending the same file and 
say if one system is sending a file containing less than the two columns from my defined `schema`
then I would like to just put `null` for those two columns and load all the other columns.

And for all the other systems, load all the fields when sent conforming to the `schema`.

How do I do this in an efficient way? I dont want to create `case class` for each system.

Comment: You can.laod data ,if column null in schema define nullable

Comment: Do you meant to say input csv file itself will not have value for some column or it would have empty data for respetive column?

Comment: It wouldn't even have some columns like if the actual `case class` or `schema` is with 25 columns then it can come with 23 columns (22 comma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process your csv data as a `Dataframe` first before converting to `Dataset`. This way, you can easily add/remove columns to match your case class with utility functions like:

```
implicit class DataFrameOps(df: DataFrame) {
  def withColumnIfNotExists(colName: String, col: Column): DataFrame = {
    if(df.columns.contains(colName)) df
    else df.withColumn(colName, col)
  }
}

// then use it like this
???.csv(filePath).withColumnIfNotExists("missing_col", lit(null).cast("string"))
```